# Select data based on admin and level who is logged in, but it displays data from another level

Tags: php, session, pdo

I am currently making a login system with multilevel. I have table **'admin'** includes **'level'** field. I want to make admin redirect to page based on 'level' field on 'admin' table. If level is **1** will redirect to **SIPP-Litbang/admin.php** page, then if level is 2 will redirect to **SIPP-Litbang/admin-pp-sipp-litbang.php**. 
The first step, I make method on class.admin.php page, here are the codes:

```
    public function login($email, $password)
    {

        try {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE email_admin = :email AND pass_admin = MD5(:pass)
LIMIT 1");
            $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':pass', $password,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();

            $adminRow = $stmt->fetch();
            if ($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {

                $_SESSION['is_logged_in'] = true;
                $_SESSION['adminSession'] = $adminRow['id_admin'];
                $_SESSION['levelSession'] = $adminRow['level'];
                return true;


            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }




        public function cekSession(){
            if (isset($_SESSION['adminSession'])&&$_SESSION['levelSession']==1) {

                header('Location: \SIPP-Litbang\admin.php');
                return true;
            }
            elseif (isset($_SESSION['adminSession'])&&$_SESSION['levelSession']==2) {

                header('Location: \SIPP-Litbang\admin-pp-sipp-litbang.php');
                return true;
            }
        }
```

And loginadmin.php page:

```
 <?php
session_start();
include_once ('class.admin.php');
$admin = new Admin();
if (isset($_POST['login'])){
    $user = trim(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
    $pass = trim(strip_tags($_POST['pass']));

    if ($admin->login($user, $pass)){

    }
    else {
        echo "GAGAL LOGIN! Email atau Password Salah";
    }
}
```

Login process has worked, for example admin with **level 2** will header to SIPP-Litbang/admin-pp-sipp-litbang?modul=beranda. Then I want to display details of admin **level 2**, here are the codes from admin-pp-sipp-litbang.php page:

```
<?php

session_start();
require_once 'class.admin.php';
$user = new ADMIN();

$admin_level = isset($_SESSION['levelSession']);
$admin_id =  isset($_SESSION['adminSession']);

$stmt = $user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE id_admin=:admin_id AND level=:level");
$stmt->bindParam(":admin_id",$admin_id);
$stmt->bindParam(":level",$admin_level);
$stmt->execute();
$userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
```

I try to echo the name of admin with **level 2**, but It just displayed name of admin with **level 1** . Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$admin_level = isset($_SESSION['levelSession']);
$admin_id =  isset($_SESSION['adminSession']);
```

`isset()` returns true\false; in your case 'true' is being cast to 1, which explains the results you see.

what i assume you want here is::

```
if(isset($_SESSION['levelSession'])){
    $admin_level =$_SESSION['levelSession'];
}

if(isset($_SESSION['adminSession'])){
    $admin_id =  $_SESSION['adminSession'];
}
```

Comment: Okay. I have removed the isset, and it works properly. Thanks for for your help